# R Multiline statement when using RSQLite

Tags: r, sqlite, rsqlite

I am having a transaction that needs to run on sqlite. The Transaction includes several queries. If built separately (line by line) it works but it requires the call of dbSendQuery n-times. It slows down the code quite a bit.

The ideal code should look like this, but multiline query fails:

```
library("RSQLite")
con <- dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(), dbname="test.db")
dbSendQuery(con, paste("CREATE TABLE Variables (Name TEXT PRIMARY KEY, RealValue REAL, IntegerValue INTEGER, BlobValue BLOB, TextValue TEXT)"))
dbSendQuery(con, paste("INSERT INTO Variables (Name) VALUES ('newid');"))
dbSendQuery(con,  paste("BEGIN IMMEDIATE TRANSACTION;",
                        "UPDATE Variables SET TextValue = '0' WHERE Name = 'newid';",
                        "UPDATE Variables SET RealValue = 0 WHERE Name = 'newid';",
                        "UPDATE Variables SET IntegerValue = 0 WHERE Name = 'newid';",
                        "COMMIT;",sep=" "))
a <- dbFetch(dbSendQuery(con, paste("SELECT * FROM _Variables;")))
dbSendQuery(con, paste("COMMIT;"))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider the [RSQLite](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RSQLite/RSQLite.pdf) methods: `dbBegin()` and `dbCommit()` (w/ `dbRollback` for any errors) to handle transactions. Even consider combining all `UPDATE` statements into one:

```
library("RSQLite")
con <- dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(), dbname="test.db")
dbSendStatement(con, "CREATE TABLE [Variables] ([Name] TEXT PRIMARY KEY, [RealValue] REAL, [IntegerValue] INTEGER, [BlobValue] BLOB, [TextValue] TEXT)")
dbSendStatement(con, "INSERT INTO [Variables] ([Name]) VALUES ('newid')")

dbBegin(con)
tryCatch({
    dbSendStatement(con, "UPDATE [Variables] SET TextValue = '0', RealValue = 0, IntegerValue = 0 WHERE [Name] = 'newid'")
}, error=function(e) dbRollback(con))
dbCommit(con)

a <- dbGetQuery(con, "SELECT * FROM [Variables]")
```

You can even combine `UPDATE` statement into one query:

Comment: the dbBegin and dbCommit is exactly what I was after! Combining the UPDATE would work but I have multiple selects in between. In fact the Variable table is a temp table to use for variables.

Comment: Great! Glad I could help. One of the fastest accepted answers. Ink wasn't even dry!